# Foreign Key issue with Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I've been looking around on here for the answer but nothing seems to work. I've done a base install of Laravel and Sentry 2. Firstly i've added this migration to add a client_id column to the users table.

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('client_id')->unique;
    });
```

Then next i created my clients table with the following in a different migration.

```
Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('client_id')->unique;
        $table->string('client_name');
        $table->date('expiry');
        $table->integer('cals');
    });
```

Finally i created a migration with the following in.

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('client_id')
            ->references('client_id')->on('clients')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

The error im getting is the following;

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint use
rs_client_id_foreign foreign key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`client_id`) on delete cascade)
```

I'm a little stuck on what i should be looking for, should they both be indexes?

Comment: Do the queries work when you run them manually (ie. using the MySQL client or phpmyadmin)?

Comment: in phpmyadmin is says no indexes defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->integer('client_id')->unique;
```

This line should read:

```
$table->integer('client_id')->unique();
```

Regardless, if you're actually trying to reference the 'id' column on the 'clients' table with a foreign key constraint on the 'users' table, then do the following:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('client_id')
        ->references('id')->on('clients')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('client_name');
    $table->date('expiry');
    $table->integer('cals');
});
```

Comment: It was the unique bit, i'm not sure how i missed it. Would the second bit actually work though as your trying to create a constraint to a table that does exist yet? (as you create it afterwards)

Comment: Yep, the second bit should work. Regardless if the table exists or not I always create one migration per table and include any foreign key constraints in that migration.